# Printing Barcode Reader Data on LCD using Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, barcode-scanner

I am trying to read Barcode Reader data over serial using Raspberry Pi and then print it on 16*2 LCD Display. I was able to read the barcode data but when i tried to print it on LCD display it doesn't print the data on display.

I tried to display int number, float and strings and it is displaying everything except Barcode Data. Can someone help. Thanks

The code that i tried is given below:

```
    import serial
    import string
    import RPi.GPIO as gpio
    import time
    import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

    port = "/dev/ttyAMA0" 
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 0.5)

    lcd_rs = 25
    lcd_en = 24
    lcd_d4 = 23
    lcd_d5 = 17
    lcd_d6 = 18
    lcd_d7 = 22
    lcd_backlight = 2

    lcd_columns = 16
    lcd_rows = 2

    lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, 
    lcd_backlight)

    while 1:

      data = ser.readline()
      print(data)
      lcd.message("Barcode:")
      lcd.message(str(data))
    time.sleep(2)
```

The data that i am getting from Barcode reader is in **Bytes** and i need to conver it to String. So i used **byte.decode("utf-8")** and then tried to display it on LCD but no Luck.

can anyone tell me how can i convert **Bytes to String**. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `data`?

Comment: Data is the Barcode Reader Values that is connected to Pi USB port

Comment: Let me make it more clear: What exactly is the value and type of `data`?

Comment: The value of Barcode that i am reading is 262717166213 and i am not sure about the type of data.

Comment: The type is rather important. Try `print(type(data))`!

Comment: Data type it prints is 'Bytes'. Output is: <class 'bytes'>262717166213

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this bit working? `lcd.message("Barcode:")`

Comment: Yeah, I am able to display everything except the Data that i am getting from Barcode Reader